# Backgrounds and z-index with tables and overflown divs

Tags: css

I am trying to figure out how to make this work. Shouldn't the background:red of the outer table's td overwrite all other ones? And why does this example end up with a yellow background although that's the element nested furthest down in the DOM?

```
<style type="text/css">
    table, td, div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
}
</style>

<table class="outer" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td style="background: red">
    <div style="overflow:auto;background:green">
    <table class="inner" style="width:800px">
        <tr>
            <td style="background:yellow"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Here's a [JSFiddle for this](http://jsfiddle.net/aTRuP/1/).

To wrap up... I am trying to overwrite the inner table cells' background color with a background in the parent div as well as the parent td of the outer table. Is that possible at all?

Comment: The cascade doesn't apply to the DOM tree. If you have a div with bgcolor green above another with bgcolor red, the red won't override the green. It's not CHTML. It's the selector that does the trick, but since the td itself has the style declared, you cannot override it with anything but Javascript, or editing the HTML itself.

Answer (score 0):

the background in the Td has the last say. so you technically can't do it with css alone. even if you put an !important in the div style it won't work.
anyways, you can probably fix that via js and replace the color of the td with another one.

Comment: yes, i've already tried the !important - doesn't work. unfortunately a javascript solution won't work since i cannot get rid of the "yellow" background. i just need to put some other background (it's actually an image) on top...

Comment: can you inject some html into that? or you can just mess around with css?

Comment: ok that's cool, because you can always set the size of the yellow TD to zero and inject into it a new div that contains all the stuff that you need, in this case the TD shall not have any kind of overflow rule applied in order to make the thinks work

Answer (score 0):

bcz its css default behavior if u give style to parent tag than it automatically inherits by child html

if u want other css in child tag than u have to give style to that particular tag
which override ur parent style

Answer (score 0):

The second `td` is always drawn above, and therefore over the top of, the background of the first `td`. As you are using the `style` attribute, which always takes precedence over any CSS applied in a `style` block or external CSS file, you will not be able to change this behaviour without resorting to JavaScript or moving the styles from the `style` attribute to a `style` block.

Using jQuery, you could achieve this with something similar to the following:

```
$('.inner td').css({
    'background' : 'colour or image here' 
});
```